# Framework7 dynamic AJAX loaded pages not working

Tags: html, ajax, frameworks, html-framework-7

I am building a framework7 app and since lots of editing has been done to one page, the AJAX loaded in pages have stopped working. I have a feeling this is to do with the structure as I ran into this problem once before, but I need someone with more experience or a better brain to help me solve this.

The problem is with the links at the end of the code that link to the chat.html page. They just do not work.

Thanks

Comment: Link to my html (the framework does work for everything else so I didn't include my js where I Initialize etc..)

https://jsfiddle.net/oh6shvh8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trial and error I found that enabling inline pages fixed my problem even though the pages I am loading in are not inline.

```
var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main', {
    domCache: true //enable inline pages
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your html needs little changes,main-view wrapper for pages,init for main-view in my-app.js. I updated your html here [Updated html code](https://jsfiddle.net/mahensharma01/bub4svxz/)

```
<div class="views"><div class="view view-main"></div></div>
```

when a view is initialized in framework7,It initializes links and other components inside it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the help, problem still not solved though. I can now swipe pages to move between them but links still do nothing. Ive updated my jsfiddle with all the needed files. go right twice to the chat page https://jsfiddle.net/bub4svxz/2/

Comment: are you appending the html dynamically? because when you append tabs/swiper dynamically you need to initialize manually. In your latest fiddle i don't see main-view wrapper in html.One view is required for framework7

Comment: I added views and view-main wrapper around pages wrapper on your fiddle.its working fine.try that out .

Comment: Ah yes, i forgot to add the change. Here https://jsfiddle.net/bub4svxz/3/ still same problem

Comment: Its the links that don't work, on the chat page there are links to chat.html. It will not load other pages

Comment: I couldn't found what problem is in your fiddle but i updated your fiddle with html. and its swipe is working. https://jsfiddle.net/mahensharma01/L3cLk79w/

Comment: Thank you for the help Mahen